# Angular dynamic named outlets

Tags: angular, router, router-outlet, angular-auxiliary-routes

I'm trying to use Angular's named outlet feature to accomplish something very specific but I can't seem to get it working.

What I'm trying to do is build a window manager. To do this I thought the new named outlets would be perfect for this.

I want to use dynamically named router outlets in modals so that I can load any route in there.

The problem is, you are required to set which named outlet a route will use in the route definitions. I won't know these ahead of time, plus a route could be loaded multiple times in multiple different outlets.

I've researched everything I can to find a way to do this with the built in router but unfortunately I've hit a roadblock.

Is there any known way to accomplish this?